Why am I getting a Coolify Docker gateway timeout when proxying to PHP?
I have a Coolify environment with a docker compose with a PHP webserver and an nginx proxy. The nginx proxy serves static files and acts as a proxy for the PHP server.
I have two domains set up in Coolify like this
https://app.example.org:80, https://static.example.org:80
This is my Docker compose file:
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    image: php:8.3-fpm-alpine
    container_name: php-app
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
#      - ./:/var/www/html
      - ./config:/var/www/html/config
      - ./backup:/var/www/html/backup
      - ./userdata:/var/www/html/userdata
      - ./.logs:/var/www/html/.logs
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    environment:
      PHP_OPCACHE_ENABLE: "1"
      PHP_OPCACHE_MEMORY_CONSUMPTION: "128"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    networks:
      - app-network

  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: nginx-web
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/sites:/etc/nginx/sites
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./shared_assets:/var/www/html/shared_assets
      - ./instances:/var/www/html/instances
    environment:
      - ENVIRONMENT=production
    ports:
      - "89:80"
    depends_on:
      - app
    networks:
      - app-network

networks:
  app-network:

For Nginx I have two sites configured
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name static.example.org;

    root /var/www/html/shared_assets;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # Serve static files from the shared_assets folder
     location /assets/ {
            alias /var/www/html/shared_assets/assets/;  # Fix the alias path to match the actual filesystem location
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name app.example.org;

    root /var/www/html/instances/app/public;
    index index.php;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}

The serving of the static files works, but the app gives me a gateway timeout. This setup works on my local machine just fine.
Any idea what the issue could be?

The issue was that fpm only was listening to requests on 127.0.0.1.
Adding
RUN sed -i 's/^listen = .*/listen = 0.0.0.0:9000/' /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf to the Dockerfile fixed the issue.
